# Two time template<typename T> declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I copied this block from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template<class T>
struct Alloc { };
template<class T>
using Vec = vector<T, Alloc<T>>; // type-id is vector<T, Alloc<T>>
Vec<int> v; // Vec<int> is the same as vector<int, Alloc<int>>
```

I dont understand why `template<typename T>` declared two time?

If `template<typename T>` declation belongs to below line it must be scoped some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template arguments are placeholders, their scope is limited to that one declaration alone.
Therefore, the `T` in

```
template<class T> struct Alloc { };
```

is not connected to the T in

```
template<class T> using Vec = vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
```

similarly as you could use the same parameter name in different function declarations.

Comment: The scope is the statement between the end of template <> and the semicolon ;

Comment: But it belongs to next line isnt it?

Comment: There are no lines in cpp, only semicolons ; or other statement ending like curly brackets }. therefore the newline is meaningless there.